# Unable to load the mojo 'sonar' - A required class is missing

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, nexus

Have been trying to set up sonar to run on my Jenkins instance at the end of each build. As there are restrictions on my work computer I have set up nexus to work as proxy so i can download artifacts from the central maven repository. Whenever I run my build it is successful and the tests pass however the sonar step fails.

```
[INFO] Building Customer 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.3:sonar (default-cli) @ Customer ---
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.543s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Mar 23 11:44:46 GMT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/156M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-  plugin:2.3:sonar (default-cli) on project Customer: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3:sonar failed: Unable to load the mojo 'sonar' in the plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/rtinfo/RuntimeInformation;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3
```

The required class that is missing - org/apache/maven/rtinfo/RuntimeInformation

I have tried several steps to resolve this already including cleaning my repository and restarting the build. I have also tried different versions of sonar-maven-plugin. I am  currently using maven 3.0.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The sonarplugin version 2.3 does not work with Maven 3.X. You have to upgrade to newest version sonar maven plugin (2.5). I hope you are not using Maven 3.0 ?

Comment: I have tried several different versions of the sonar maven plugin including 2.5. And yes i am using maven 3.0, is that a problem? I get exactly the same error using plugin version 2.5

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of Maven? I would recommend to update to at least 3.0.5 cause there have been many bug fixes in the meantime. Furthermore can you show the full pom file of this project? Or can you make a full working example which reproduces the problem? Do you have any kind of WARNINGs during the build of this project? Maybe connection problems etc.?

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using?

Comment: Sonarqube Version 5.0

I am restricted with the version of maven I am using because there are other jobs which cannot run on a newer version on maven so we have had to stick with 3.0. I know this is not helpful, but it is not something I can change as the jobs belong to several teams not just my own

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **Apache Maven 3.2.5** in combination with **org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1**.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- ... -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```